# In a data frame, repeat / complete rows based on multiples months extraction

Tags: r

I have a dataframe :

```
details <- "I stay in april in Barcelona, after in may in Paris and finally in july in London. april is a cool month. july has very hot temperatures"

df <- as.data.frame(details)
```

I can extract months words before cities in a new colmun witth `mutate`and `str_extract` from `tidyverse` package:

```
 library(tidyverse)
 dfmonths<-  df %>%
  mutate(city_months = str_extract(details, "april|may|july(?=\\sin)")
```

...but only the fist matched month is in my result :

```
details                                                               city_months
1 I stay in april in Barcelona (...) and finally in july in Paris.... april
```

I tried :

```
 library(tidyverse)
  dfmonths<-  df %>%
   mutate(city_months = str_extract_all(details, 
   "april|may|july(?=\\sin)")
```

but I have only one row :

```
details                                                               city_months
1 I stay in april in Barcelona (...) and finally in july in Paris.... april, may, july
```

How can I do that :

```
details                                                              city_months
1 I stay in april in Barcelona (...) and finally in july in Paris....april
2 I stay in april in Barcelona (...) and finally in july in Paris.... may
3 I stay in april in Barcelona (...) and finally in july in Paris....july
```

Comment: So do you want to have multiple rows for each row in your original data.frame? Also your mre is kind of broken/incomplete...

Comment: @dario  yes, with a new column with months

Comment: @dario I made a few updates to my question. In think my question is clear and I made some research efforts

Comment: @dario sorry.  My question was downvote.

Comment: @dario. Your are true. Sorry.

Comment: It's all good ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str_extract_all`, i.e

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
 mutate(new = str_extract_all(details, "april|may|july(?=\\sin)")) %>% 
 unnest() %>%
 distinct()

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  details                                                                                                                                  new  
  <chr>                                                                                                                                    <chr>
1 I stay in april in Barcelona, after in may in Paris and finally in july in London. april is a cool month. july has very hot temperatures april
2 I stay in april in Barcelona, after in may in Paris and finally in july in London. april is a cool month. july has very hot temperatures may  
3 I stay in april in Barcelona, after in may in Paris and finally in july in London. april is a cool month. july has very hot temperatures july
```

Comment: I  tryied using extract_all but didnt conbined unnest and distinct functions. Thank you.